# Visualizing of frequency of integer data in R

Tags: r, plot, integer, histogram

When I try to visualize my integer data with *histogram(mydata,breaks=c(0,n))*, R usually doesnt care about how many breaks (usually 1 bar for each sample) do I use and it plots n-1 bars (first two bars are summed into one).

In most cases I use *barplot(table(mydata))*

And there is one more way to do it
[How to separate the two leftmost bins of a histogram in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392647/how-to-separate-the-two-leftmost-bins-of-a-histogram-in-r)
but I think its not "clear" way.

So how do you visualize frequency of your integer data? 
Which one is right?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
hist(dataset, breaks=seq(min(dataset)-0.5, max(dataset)+0.5, by=1)  )
```

Another option (for thos situations where you *know* these are integers would be:

```
require(lattice) 
barchart(table(dataset), horizontal=FALSE)
```

Or:

```
barplot(table(dataset))
```