# Breaks in between bars, R histogram

Tags: r, histogram

data:

```
varx <- c(1.234, 1.32, 1.54, 2.1 , 2.76, 3.2, 4.56, 5.123, 6.1, 6.9)

hist(varx)
```

Gives me

[image]

What I would like to do is create the same histogram but with spaces in between the bars.

I've tried what is found here [How to separate the two leftmost bins of a histogram in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392647/how-to-separate-the-two-leftmost-bins-of-a-histogram-in-r)

But no luck.

When I do it on my actual data I get:

[image]

This is my actual data:

```
a <- c(2.6667
,4.45238
,5.80952
,3.09524
,3.52381
,4.04762
,4.53488
,3.80952
,5.7619
,3.42857
,4.57143
,6.04762
,4.02381
,5.47619
,4.09524
,6.18182
,4.85714
,4.52381
,5.61905
,4.90476
,4.42857
,5.31818
,2.47619
,5
,2.78571
,4.61905
,3.71429
,2.47619
,4.33333
,4.80952
,6.52381
,5.06349
,4.06977
,5.2381
,5.90476
,4.04762
,3.95238
,2.42857
,4.38333
,4.225
,3.96667
,3.875
,3.375
,4.18333
,5.45
,4.45
,3.76667
,4.975
,2.2
,5.53846
,6.1
,5.9
,4.25
,5.7
,3.475
,3.5
,4
,4.38333
,3.81667
,3.9661
,1.2332
,1.2443
,5.4323
,2.324
,1.342
,1.321
,3.81667
,3.9661
,1.2332
,1.2443
,5.4323
,2.324
,1.342
,1.321
,4.32
,6.43
,6.98
,4.321
,3.253
,2.123
,1.234)
```

Why do I get these skinny bars and how do I remove them?

Answer (score 1):

The code works, but needs smaller numbers:

```
varx <-  c(1.234, 1.32, 1.54, 2.1 , 2.76, 3.2, 4.56, 5.123, 6.1, 6.9)


hist(varx, breaks=rep(1:7,each=2)+c(-.04,.04), freq=T)
```

This returns a warning as it prefers to return "density" instead of "frequency" after manually changing the breaks in that way. Change to freq=F if you prefer.

Comment: Yes, that's why I  mentioned that the code works in this case as well, but needs smaller numbers in the breaks.

Answer (score 1):

In general this is a bad idea - histograms show the continuity of data, and gaps ruin that. You can use the previous code with smaller gaps (your values hit the previous gaps):

```
hist(varx,breaks=rep(1:7,each=2)+c(-.05,.05))
```

But this is not a general solution - any values closer than 0.05 to the cutoff will end up in the gap region.

We can make a bar plot of factored data using `ggplot2`, depending on how you want to round values. In this case, I have taken the floor (rounds down to nearest integer), and rounded to the nearest integer:

```
library(ggplot2)
varx <- as.data.frame(varx)
varx$floor <- floor(varx$varx)
varx$round <- round(varx$varx)
ggplot(varx, aes(x = as.factor(floor))) + geom_bar()
ggplot(varx, aes(x = as.factor(round))) + geom_bar()
```

[image: floor]
[image: round]

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is looking for a more vanilla solution, you can just set the `border` argument for `hist` to be the same color as the background of the plot:

```
par(mfrow=1:2)
# connected bars
hist(y <- rnorm(100))

# seemingly disconnected bars
hist(y, border=par('bg'))
```

[Adding artificial separation between bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW8UM.png)