# How to separate bins when plotting histogram from a discrete values

Tags: r

I'm using following code to plot histogram from discrete values:

```
vect=c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5,1)
h1=hist(vect, breaks=1:max(vect), right=FALSE)
```

The output of this is following:

[image]

My goal is to have bins separated as it is in following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392647/how-to-separate-the-two-leftmost-bins-of-a-histogram-in-r). I've also tried to apply the code from mentioned post:

```
vect=c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5,1)
h1=hist(vect, breaks=1:rep(vect,each=2)+c(-.4,.4), right=FALSE)
```

but it gives an error. 2nd attempt was following code suggested by @TheTime:

```
vect=c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5,1)
h1=hist(vect, breaks=rep(1:max(vect),each=2)+c(-.4,.4), right=FALSE)
```

This returned:
[image]

As you can see there are some weird numbers 1 has value 1.6, 2 has value 1.4 etc.

```
> h1$breaks
 [1] 0.6 1.4 1.6 2.4 2.6 3.4 3.6 4.4 4.6 5.4
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the breaks looks wrong, try `breaks=rep(1:max(vect),each=2)+c(-.4,.4)`

Comment: @TheTime thank you for reply. Seems that `barplot` version is working. Version with `breaks` gives some weird numbers, can you please explain why? Thank you

Comment: @TheTime I've edited OP. Thank you.

Comment: @TheTime `vect=c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5,1)
h1=hist(vect, breaks=rep(1:max(vect),each=2)+c(-.4,.4), right=FALSE, freq=FALSE)` gives the same results as `vect=c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5,1)
h1=hist(vect, breaks=rep(1:max(vect),each=2)+c(-.4,.4), right=FALSE)`

Comment: @TheTime Oh I see, please make your comment as answer so I can accept it.